# Java print writer seems to detect file, but it does not write

Tags: java, file, url, uri, printwriter

I am using Netbeans on OS X and cannot seem to write text to a text file that I have in a package named "assets".

Below is the way I tried to accomplish writing to the text file and so far my method of doing this is not working.

The way I tried to approach this problem was converting a string to url, then converting the url to a uri. Then I used the uri for the new file parameter. After I tried to write a string using the class print writer.

```
public class Experiment {

File createFile(String path) {
    java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource(path);
    URI uri;
    try {
        uri = url.toURI();
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        uri = null;
    }
    if ((url != null) && (uri != null)) {
        System.out.println("file loading sucess");
        return new File(uri);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error file has not been loaded");
        return null;
    }
}

File file = createFile("/assets/myfile.txt");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Experiment testrun = new Experiment();
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(testrun.file));
        writer.println("it works");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

        System.out.println("string was written");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("there was an error while writing");
    }
}
}
```

The output given from my try catch statements say that the file write code was executed.

```
file loading sucess
string was written
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I have also tried using absolute string paths for making a new file, but with null results. I am running out of ideas and hoping for some guidance or solution from somebody.

Comment: Pleae check the build of your project. The folder in which the compiled classes are placed by the ide. The file in that folder is the one to which output will go to. E.g: for eclipse it is usually <projectdir>/bin/classes

Comment: What should I do or put in the classes folder

Comment: Since, you are going to modify the file, do not put in the classes/resources folder. Those should be used only for read only files from which you read some application configurations. I would suggest creating a seperate directory in your system for the file.